# error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct node')

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, structure

Why cant i access the pointer "Cells" like an array ? i have allocated the appropriate memory why wont it act like an array here? it works like an array for a pointer of basic data types.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX 10
struct node
{
    int e;
    struct node *next;
};  

typedef struct node *List;
typedef struct node *Position;

struct Hashtable
{
    int Tablesize;
    List Cells;
};

typedef struct Hashtable *HashT;

HashT Initialize(int SIZE,HashT H)
{   
    int i;
    H=(HashT)malloc(sizeof(struct Hashtable));
    if(H!=NULL)
    {
        H->Tablesize=SIZE;
        printf("\n\t%d",H->Tablesize);
        H->Cells=(List)malloc(sizeof(struct node)* H->Tablesize);
```

should it not act like an array from here on?

```
        if(H->Cells!=NULL)
        {
            for(i=0;i<H->Tablesize;i++)
```

the following lines are the ones that throw the error

```
            { H->Cells[i]->next=NULL;
              H->Cells[i]->e=i;
                printf("\n %d",H->Cells[i]->e);
            }
         }
     }
     else printf("\nError!Out of Space");
}

int main()
{  
    HashT H;
    H=Initialize(10,H);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is as in the title-error: `invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct node').`

Comment: First, indent your code.

Comment: `H->Cells->[i]e` is definitely not correct syntax.

Comment: And then note that `H->Cells->[i]e=i;` is not C syntax.

Comment: Stylistic comment. typedef considered harmful: you are confusing yourself by hiding pointers inside a typedef. This is confusing because there are now three ways (instead of just two or one) to refer to the same type. And: the `->` should probably just be `.` Plus: using one letter all-caps names for variables is confusing, too. Plus: don't cast malloc()s return value. casting adds visual clutter, is not necessary and potentially dangerous.

Comment: `Initialize(int SIZE,HashT H)` the parameter `H` is not needed. and it is immediately overwritten by the malloc() call inside the function. If it were supplied by the caller this could even be a potential memory leak. BTW: what is Cells supposed to be an array of items, or an array of pointers to items?

Comment: Cells is supposed to be an array of pointers  to items

Answer (score 1):

A correct version of your code is given below. It is always advisable not to use pointers while using typedef.

The only problem with your code apart from that was your access method.
`H->cells[i]->next` will throw an error.

Also `H->cells->[i]e` was invalid syntax.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX 10
struct node
{
    int e;
    struct node *next;
};  
typedef struct node List;
typedef struct node Position;
struct Hashtable
{
    int Tablesize;
    List *Cells;
};
typedef struct Hashtable HashT;

HashT Initialize(int SIZE,HashT *H)
{   
    int i;
    H=(HashT*)malloc(sizeof(struct Hashtable));
    if(H!=NULL)
    {
         H->Tablesize=SIZE;
         printf("\n\t%d",H->Tablesize);
         H->Cells=(List*)malloc(sizeof(List)*H->Tablesize);
     //should it not act like an array from here on?
         if(H->Cells!=NULL)
         {
             for(i=0;i<H->Tablesize;i++)
    //the following lines are the ones that throw the error
             { 
                 H->Cells[i].next=NULL;
                 H->Cells[i].e=i;
                 printf("\n %d",H->Cells[i].e);
             }
         }
    }
    else printf("\nError!Out of Space");
    return *H;
 }

 int main()
 {  
     HashT H;
     H=Initialize(10,&H); //return is not required as already we are passing by address
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: in this code , would it be possible to access next and e like this : H->Cells[i]->e?? if not why not because 'Cells' is a pointer to a structure itself right?

Comment: No it is not possible.
`Cells` is of type `List*` and `Cells[i]` is of type `List and NOT List*`.
The arrow operator can only be used with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
H->Cells[i]->next
```

should be

```
H->Cells[i].next
```

(Similarly for `e`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of your program without the typedefs. Which one is more readable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int e;
    };

struct Hashtable {
    unsigned Tablesize;
    struct node *Cells;
    };

struct Hashtable *Initialize(unsigned size)
{
    unsigned iii;
    struct Hashtable *hp;

    hp = malloc (sizeof *hp);
    if(!hp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error!Out of Space\n");
        return NULL;
        }

    hp->Cells = malloc(size * sizeof *hp->Cells );
    if(!hp->Cells) {
           hp->Tablesize = 0;
           return hp;
           }

    hp->Tablesize = size;
    fprintf(stderr, "\t%u\n", hp->Tablesize);
    for(iii=0; iii < hp->Tablesize; iii++) {
         hp->Cells[iii].next = NULL;
         hp->Cells[iii].e = iii;
         fprintf( stderr, " %u\n", hp->Cells[iii].e);
         }
    return hp;
 }

 int main()
 {
    struct Hashtable *hashtab;

     hashtab = Initialize(10);
     return 0;
 }
```

The changes:

- removed the typedefs; since they are confusing
- removed the casts from malloc() not needed and potentially dangerous.
- changed the sizes to unsigned. A size can never be negative
- diagnostic output should go to stderr.
- a few of levels of indentation can be avoided by doing the error-case first, and returning early from the function on error.